# OpenID not working - gmail

Tags: facebook, openid

I registered with facebook longback using my email ID xxxxxx@hotmail.com.
Now I added my gmail ID xxxxxx@gmail.com

I want to use OpenID for logging into facebook - first I want to log into my gmail using my gmail ID and gmail pasword, then I open facebook in a new TAB (in the same browser) it should not ask for my facebook username & Facebook password.

But it is not working in my case, even after logging in gmail, facebook is asking for facebook user ID and facebook password.

Can you please help with the right procedure for using openID (i.e. gmail login with gmail user credentials for facebook).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Facebook supports OpenID login. You either can use OpenID for Google Account or use Facebook's own login scheme and perhaps OAuth too.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/